# How do I set up a gradle Java project with shared inter-dependencies?

Tags: java, gradle, jar, subproject, source-sets

I have a Java project consisting of the following parts:

- a Java library with

  - production code
  - integration tests for that library
- an demo Java application using that library

The integration tests and the demo application share some code, as there are examples that can be chosen and run in the demo application, and all these examples are also exercised by the integration tests. Thus the code has the following four parts:

- library production code
- library integration tests
- demo application
- examples code

It seems obvious to me (please correct me if I'm wrong) that the library production code and the library integration tests should be separate source sets, but in the same module ( = same Gradle subproject).

As the demo application uses different Gradle plugins than the library (`java` + `application` vs. `java-library`), I've made it a separate module ( = separate Gradle subproject).

The code parts have the following dependencies on each other:

- The demo application calls the examples code and directly some of the library production code
- The integration tests call the examples code and directly some of the library production code
- The examples call the library production code

To avoid a circular dependency, I did **not** make the examples a separate module (Gradle subproject), but another source set within the library's module.

Thus my project has the following structure:

```
my-multi-module-project/
├── build.gradle
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
├── settings.gradle
├── demo-application/
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── src/
│       └── main/
│           └── java/
│               └── ...
├── build.gradle
└── my-library/
    ├── build.gradle
    └── src/
        ├── main/
        │   └── java/
        │       └── ...
        ├── test/
        │   └── java/
        │       └── ...
        └── example/
            └── java/
                └── ...
```

... with the following in `my-multi-module-project/settings.gradle`:

```
rootProject.name = 'my-multi-module-project'

include 'my-library'
include 'demo-application'
```

Does this project structure make sense for this project, or should I change it?

And **how should I set up those dependencies between the source sets, which aren't already handled by the used plugins' defaults?**

I've tried with a custom configuration `exampleOutput` in the library module:

Content of `my-multi-module-project/build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'base'
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Content of `my-multi-module-project/demo-application/build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(path: ':my-library', configuration: 'exampleOutput')
    implementation project(path: ':my-library')
}

run {
    standardInput = System.in
}

mainClassName = 'com.example.mylibrary.demoapplication.MainClass'
```

Content of `my-multi-module-project/my-library/build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
}

sourceSets {
    example {
        java
        resources

        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
        runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
    }

    test {
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.example.output
        runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.example.output
    }
}

configurations {
    exampleOutput
}

dependencies {
    exampleOutput sourceSets.example.output

    // Use JUnit test framework
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.4.2")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.4.2")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.4.2")
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

This works fine with `./gradlew run` and `./gradlew test`.

But now I need an installation for production, where Gradle shall not be used. So I run

```bash
./gradlew installDist
```

and then try to run

```bash
./demo-application/build/install/demo-application/bin/demo-application
```

I get a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` about a class in from the `example` code part and indeed, in `demo-application/build/install/demo-application/lib`, there a JAR file for the library production code (`my-library.jar`) and one for the demo application (`demo-application.jar`), but none for the examples. Instead, there's a folder structure corresponding to the `example` source set's Java package structure containing `*.class` files of the example Java classes.

Consequently the archives produced by `./gradlew distZip` and `./gradlew distTar` are similarly unusable.

**How do I configure my project, so that installation / production of distributables works correctly, too?**